# Create table of 2 related measures

Tags: powerbi

I have a table of 3 columns: UserID, OrderID, Status and Date

I want to create a table showing how many users made 1 order, how many made 2 orders and so on, with a date slicer.

I got my desired output (except the slicer part) using a calculated table:

```
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('F_ORDER'[OrderID]), FILTER('F_ORDER', 'F_ORDER'[status] ="SUCCESS")))
```

However, slicer only works on measures, not calculated table. Since both Count of OrderID and Count of UserID are both measures, I believe there is a work around.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you want to filter a subset of data using a calculus based on the subset current of data (users with certain DISTINCTCOUNT('F_ORDER'[OrderID])). Power bi doesnt allow this because sometimes this would involve problematic calculus or nonending loops. Not in your case but it is in the same box...

Workaround?
I dont think there is a way to make exactly that. If you REALLY need and you dont have many distinctcount values you could create 1 column and 1 filter per value to filter (in the same panel or different panels).

If you have many distinctcount values, I would suggest using a table with conditional formatting. You CAN use measures for this. All the Users would be in the table but you would order the correct ones on the top and set the font color on green, while the others would be in red or in the same color as the background.

Hope that helped,
Regards!